# Protecting custom inline elements in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I'm currently spiking with the WPF `RichTextBox` before I decide whether or not it can be used in a project of mine.

What I need is to have elements of text representing various objects (other texts or objects), a bit like a WIKI but not quite. Clicking on such a text will make stuff happen, like navigating to other texts or providing additional options.

Anyway, as these little text bits represent other objects I would like to protect them but I have succeeded with this only in part: The user cannot position a caret inside such a text element and edit/delete it but it is still possible to make a selection and delete/replace it, including my custom elements.

Have anyone travelled down this road with the `RichTextBox`? My latest experiment was to simply record all custom text elements when being part of a selection and then restoring them after the (destructive) edit. That fell apart because I can't find a way to re-insert my custom inline elements (derived from the `Run` class). The only way I've found to programmatically insert a Run (based) element at a specified position (`TextPosition`) is via its constructor.

Well, any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would love to see your code, since I am trying to do something similar.  I my case I want the user to be able to edit/delete the runs, but I want to know what they did to the specific run.

Answer (score 0):

You are really looking for a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx),  not a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The `RichTextBox.Document` _is_ a `FlowDocument` or am I missing something?

Comment: @JonasRembratt You're using a control that has end user editing capabilities, but then you want to disable those capabilities. Just use a `FlowDocumentScrollReader` or other type of `Reader` instead.